Return unique values from list to unique entry and matching values to duplicates in Google Sheets
given a list of names in an array A:A
for every unique value print to B:B the first value in C:C
if the value in A:A isnt unique then return the same value returned above
for example, in the table below if I were to add a unique value to A9 (the next line) then the output value in B9 would be "Grape"



Name
Output
List




John Smith
Apple
Apple


Sam Smith
Pear
Pear


Charles Big H
Banana
Banana


John Smith
Apple
Peach


John Smith
Apple
Grape


Sam Smith
Pear
Mango


Charles Big
Peach
Orange





You may try:
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,iferror(chooserows(tocol(C2:C,1),xmatch(Σ,unique(A2:A))),"-_-"))))



is there a faster way to accomplish?
